# linux command to combine two tar.gz files

Tags: linux

I have a tar.gz file that is split into two files for example x.tar.gz.00 and x.tar.gz.01. How to combine these two tar files in linux?

I tried with this below command but no success.

```
zcat X.tar.gz.00 X.tar.gz.01 | gzip -c > X.tar.gz.
```

It returned

```
gzip: X.tar.gz.00: unexpected end of file
```

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on how it was split. If it was split by tar or gzip themselves, have you tried just unpacking the first to see if it will automatically continue with the second?

Answer (score 8):

If you split the file after compressing it, as the error suggests, then just concatenate the files directly:

```
cat X.tar.gz.00 X.tar.gz.01 > X.tar.gz
```

Comment: I guess that is the only solution, but I hate it to concatenate 4 files of 5 Gbyte, just to find out what is inside. At least ican confirm this worked for the android archive of the Orange Pi one plus.

Comment: After doing this, `tar -tf` does not show the merged tars' files

Comment: @alper Are you sure you split a single tar file rather than creating two independent tar files?

Comment: Ah I was trying to merge two independent tar files that's why it wasn't working

Comment: is it possible that this behavior has been disabled in recent tar versions?

Comment: @filippo What behavior? `tar` doesn't have any built-in splitting or joining feature AFAIK.

Comment: @Barmar sorry I misread your answer, I had a script that used plain `cat` to concatenate tar.gz files and I was able to extract everything from the final tar.gz file, at some point it must have stopped working... I fixed it using `tar -A` to concatenate tar files and gzipping them later. Sorry for the noise!